# Azure on-premises local AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have a local on-premises AD server configured to be synced with azure.
The employee who configured this left the company, and we want it removed.
The problem is: my user, which is the owner of all the microsoft subscriptions (including our production environment in azure) is synced with this local AD.

I need to remove my user from the local on-premises AD and keep it only in the cloud. If i just remove it from the local on-premises server, will it affect my subscriptions in anyway? Also, how can i put it back to be just synced with the cloud?

[image: Here is a picture with the users and how they appear.]

Comment: When i'm trying to delete a synced account i get this error: "Couldn’t delete this user because the account is synchronized with your on-premises servers. You can delete the user from your on-premises server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would want to take a look at this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2619062). So generally no, you cannot do that. Unless you want something really hackish.

Comment: I have seen that article. But if i follow those steps, with the intention of completely removing the local AD server, will this affect my current subscription by any means? (i'm interested in having no downtime of my VMs in azure)

Comment: no, if you just turn off the sync nothing bad happens.

Comment: Great, i have turned off the sync, it says there that it can take up to 72 hours to process. After this, i'm guessing i can delete the whole on-premise thing from the azure portal (or from the office365 portal)